# How to mock a service method with iteration in a loop?

Tags: java, unit-testing, loops, mockito

I am trying to do an Unit test of a method that has a loop in it.

Basically, the method looks like this:

```
public List<Discount> methodName(Request request){
    for (Discount discountIteration: request.getList()) {
        applyDiscount(service1.getCode(discountIteration));
    }
    ...
}
```

So, i don't know how to mock the `service1.getCode(discountIteration)`.

Should i do a `when(...).thenReturn(...);` of each position of the `request.getList()` (this is a list of a custome object).

Or is there any way to do it dynamically?

Edit: I'm trying to mock the `method` inside the loop, not the `List`

Comment: @CodeMatrix The OP wants to mock the `getCode()` invocation, not `getList()`.

Comment: You iterate on a `discountList` variable but you never use it. Not very clear. And What is `discountIteration` ? Please provide a MCVE  :https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry that was wrong, i just edit it. The answer of that that question, doesn't help me cause i don't want to mock the list, i got the list already. @davidxxx

Comment: I know that. I say exactly that in my first comment. I added my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `any` Argument Matcher.

```
when(service1.getCode(any(DiscountIteration.class)).thenReturn(valueYouWantToReturn);
```

Keep in mind that the `valueYouWantToReturn` will be the same for every entry in the list

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Awesome, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Paplusc glad to help. Also when you have some spare time take a look over David's answer as it also contains very useful insight

Answer (score 3):

> Should i do a `when(...).thenReturn(...);` of each position of the
>   `request.getList()` (this is a list of a custome object).
>
> Or is there any way to do it dynamically?

I would do neither of them but I would refactor the code to make coupling less small grain between classes for this use case.
With so small grain coupling, mocking will require much boiler plate code, not be straight readable and the test maintainability will be weak.

You could change the `service1.getCode()` method or add a new in this way :

```
public List<Discount> methodName(Request request){
    List<Code> codes = service1.getCodes(request.getList());
    for (int i = 0; i < discountIteration.size(); i++) {
        Discount discountIteration = request.getList().get(i);
        applyDiscount(codes.get(i));
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you just need to mock the List returned by `getCodes()`.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx i fixed it with `any` but i will refactor my code as you said. I appreciate that.